# Are there any 20v to 240v step up transformers in the market?

Tags: power, transformer, ac, inverter, ac-motor

I'm constructing a AC motor driver for a project that will take in a DC voltage source and output an AC voltage fit for an AC-motor. I didn't have prior experience with power electronics or power inverters so one thing that shocked me was how high the supply voltage was for cheap AC motors (110-240VAC). My plan is the following:

Use a microcontroller to make PWM impulses to a H bridge that then outputs the sine wave to a step up transformer whose output connects to an AC motor. I've constructed an H bridge and I've picked a suitable MCU, but I'm having trouble with the transformer and AC motor. This circuit could be a lot easier with a low voltage transformer and AC motor but I can't find one. I have a 24v battery to power the H bridge which will output 20v for the transformer. The problem is that I can't find a step up transformer online that can output up to 240v from a ~20v input. Does anybody have any experience with this that can share tips on how to make this more effective?

Comment: Transformers are expensive for motor power. You better have good specs or deep pockets

Comment: Why can’t you control the mains power to the motor, rather than stepping up the voltage?

Comment: Step down = up! Power (VA=tbd)? HP=? 0.1 , 1?

Comment: HandyHowie just to clarify, do you mean that the battery should drive the AC?

Comment: No, is a mains 110v or 240v supply not available?  Does it have to be powered by the battery?

Comment: I want to learn how power inverters work, so that is why I'm going through the trouble of converting from DC to AC

Comment: Do you know how to compute impedance ratios and stall/start current ratios? Control acceleration? Use V/f?  $$ https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/isolation-transformers-and-autotransformers-step-up-step-down/167?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvsQC0AJmQg0kLgFcipCiCTEArHSEiQkyJQAqnTL1zoSnALb5OdYgDYp3ACatRYKhEYtIIEMSYAngz4rJi4aFpAA

Comment: Assuming you're happy with single phase fixed frequency AC, just buy a 24V input AC inverter. Common and cheap.

Comment: Tony Stewart EE75 I know about impedance ratios, but not much about the other topics

Comment: You must learn this and compute impedance for losses then write specs before you design anything

Comment: Could you update your question to include the [horse]power rating of the motor you'd like to control?  It is important.  You need a high-current, low-voltage DC source to switch. (For a 20V:240V transformer ratio, primary current = 12 × secondary.)  BTW, a common topology for a variable-frequency motor drive puts a transformer at the mains *input*, rectifies & switches DC on the order of the peak output voltage. Building a small VFD might be just as educational, but make sure to buy more than one motor, since you're likely to damage the windings on the first one with switching transients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question as posed:
A transformer is a passive component and has no fundamental distinction between "input" and "output" - if you drive the "output" of a "step-down" transformer with a low-voltage AC signal you will see a high-voltage AC signal at the "input", and you have a "step-up" transformer. The relationship between the two voltages is fixed by the turns ratio, so a 240:20 "step-down" transformer is also a 20:240 "step-up" transformer when driven "in reverse".

Things get more tricky when you draw a non-trivial amount of current from the effective-secondary, and also when magnetizing the core requires a non-trivial amount of current in the effective-primary. How much is "non-trivial" depends on DC resistance (and thus the wire size) of the windings, and those windings may have been optimized for the original design use-case of the transformer.

If your goal is "to learn how inverters work", forget the transformer and motor, make a load impedance appropriate to the rest of your circuit, and look at signals on your oscilloscope. (You *do* have an oscilloscope, right?)